# PrimeNg/Angular: How to display the label of a selected item?

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

.html:

```
<p-listbox formControlName="userRole" 
           [options]="this.userRoleItems"   
           [(ngModel)]="selectedUserProfile.role" 
           multiple="multiple" 
           [style]='{"width":"250px"}' 
           checkbox="checkbox" filter="filter">
</p-listbox>
```

Selected Roles:

```
<span *ngFor="let c of selectedUserProfile.role" style="margin-right: 10px"> 
  {{c}}
</span>
```

.ts file:

```
userRoleItems: SelectItem[] = [
  { label:  'User Role 1', value: 1 }, 
  { label:  'User Role 2', value: 2 }, 
  { label:  'User Role 1', value: 3 }
];
```

However i  want to display the label instead of the value when one is selected

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your *.component.ts you can define a method:

```
labelByValue(value){
    let i =  this.userRoleItems.find(item => item.value == value);
    return i ? i.label : "";
  }
```

In your *.component.htm use it like below:

```
<span *ngFor="let c of selectedUserProfile.role" style="margin-right: 10px"> 
  {{labelByValue(c)}}
</span>
```

[Plunkr demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/iY45aU6clv8VpJZtPJSk?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with something like this:

```
const labels = userRoleItems.filter(ur => selectedUserProfile.role.indexOf(ur.value) !== 1);
```

Then you can loop through labels array and print only label field.
Please note that the code is not tested, since I don't have full example